# ros2 merging maps for multi-robot exploration

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i'm trying to merge  maps generated from multiple robots in a simulation however i noticed that the map_merger package doesnt exist in ros2. Does anyone know a way to merge maps in ros2 ?

thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378760/ros2-merging-maps-for-multi-robot-exploration/) by [Nick_JR](https://answers.ros.org/users/56383/nick_jr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2021-05-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Richard Mark Haes Ellis](https://answers.ros.org/users/76692/richard-mark-haes-ellis/) on 2021-11-25**:
I'm having the same issue aswell, did you manage to solve the problem?

**Comment by [Nick_JR](https://answers.ros.org/users/56383/nick_jr/) on 2021-11-26**:
Sadly i didn't, i went back to ros 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Nick. I just finished porting multirobot_map_merge package to ROS2. You can check it out at https://github.com/robo-friends/m-explore-ros2#multirobot-map-merge
Hope it helps future people or you and any feedback or report is welcome!

---

Originally posted by [charlie92](https://answers.ros.org/users/64524/charlie92/) with karma: 87 on 2021-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SBSF](https://answers.ros.org/users/140976/sbsf/) on 2023-02-28**:
Hi Charlie, We tried the package in foxy for multi robobts with slam-gmapping - rviz and gazebo all started fine but could not navigate in rviz as the goal is always rejected by the server for both robots. Rviz for map merge is empty.

We tried it in Galactic - launches fine, could navigate both robots in rviz, could run map merge it subscribes to /robot1/map and /robot2/map and map_updates but rviz for map merge is empty